# What is the best practice for checking if the edit not empty

Tags: delphi

I'm wondering about the best practice to validate an edit is not empty

```
  if edt1.Text <> '' then
    //DoSomething
  else
  ShowMessage('Check 1');

  if edt1.Text = '' then
  ShowMessage('Check 2')
  else
  //DoSomething
```

Comment: Apart from the info provided in Remy's answer, there is no "best practice" regarding which way to orient your **if** conditions. The choice between `if <positive-condition> then DoA else DoB;` versus `if <negative-condition> then DoB else DoA;` is arbitrary. Sometimes one will read better than the other in a certain piece of code - so choose the one that makes the code clearer. I repeat, there is no "best practice" in this regard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading the `Text` property loads the Edit's current content into memory as a temporary `String` .  If you just want to check if the Edit is empty, there is a more efficient way to do that:

```
if edt1.GetTextLen > 0 then
  // not empty
else
  // empty
```

Of course, the length will be `> 0` if the Edit contains any characters at all, even if just whitespace.  If you need to ignore leading/trailing whitespace, you have no choice but to retrieve the full `Text` and trim it:

```
if Trim(edt1.Text) <> '' then
  // not empty
else
  // empty
```

Comment: Instead '' use EmptyStr (this is constant)

Comment: `EmptyStr` is a global variable (and not a constant variable at that!).  There is no benefit to using `EmptyStr` over `''`. Even the source code for the `SysUtils` unit says that `EmptyStr` is "provided for backwards compatibility only". Embarcadero's [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declaring_and_Initializing_Strings) says: "To test a string for empty you can either use the EmptyStr variable ... or test against an empty string".